# if $d'(x_1, x_2)=\min(1, d(x_1, x_2))$, is $d'$ a metric on $X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm given the problem:

> If $d'(x_1, x_2)=\min(1, d(x_1, x_2))$, is $d'$ a metric on $X$?

I'm stuck in the triangular inequality. Since we have to show that

$$ d'(x_1, x_3) \leq d'(x_1, x_2) + d'(x_2, x_3) $$

there is a case in which I'm confused:

1. If $\min(1, d(x_1, x_3))$ is $1$, and $\min(1, d(x_1, x_2))$ and $\min(1, d(x_2, x_3))$ are $d(x_1, x_2)$ and $d(x_2, x_3)$ respectively. What if the values of $d(x_1, x_2)$ and $d(x_2, x_3)$ are less than $0.5$ and there sum isn't $1$ or greater than $1$?

I don't know if I am thinking the right way or there is some mistake in it. Please help me with this problem!

Comment: Please format your question with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'll try to overcome this issue. Does this question still need to be edited?

Comment: The question looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re almost done.

Just remember that

$1=d’(x_1,x_3) \leq d(x_1,x_3) \leq d(x_1,x_2) + d(x_2,x_3)$.

It’s very important that you make sure that you have used every hypothesis in a exercice. Otherwise, something is likely missing in your proof or you’ve proved a more general statement which is unlikely.